# MongoDb Efficient connection creation

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to know the most efficient way to create /close MongoDb Connections.

I have a set of Restful services (created using c#), some of them get data form a MongoDb and some POST data in.

```
   public static MongoDatabase GetDatabase()
   {
      MongoServerSettings settings = new MongoServerSettings();
      settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
      MongoServer server = new MongoServer(settings);
      var database = server.GetDatabase("RapidDataStream");
      return database;
   }
```

I use the above connection form each of my services, for example a service to list all sensors.

```
public List<Sensor> getPublicSensors()
{
            List<Sensor> sensors = new List<Sensor>();
            MongoDatabase mySensor = GetDatabase();
            var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("User", BsonValue.Create("Public")));
            var mySensorRecords = mySensor.GetCollection("sensor_meta_data").Find(query);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            foreach (var rec in mySensorRecords)
            {
                Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
                sensor.sensorId = rec["EnvId"].ToString();

                for (int i = 2; i < rec.ElementCount; i++)
                {
                    SensorObject so = new SensorObject();
                    so.fieldName = rec.GetElement(i).Name.ToString();
                    so.value = rec.GetElement(i).Value.ToString();
                    sensor.sensorObject.Add(so);
                }
                sensors.Add(sensor);
            }
            return sensors;
}
```

My question is that whether this is an efficient design or else how can I improve it?

Many Thanks.

Comment: For one, I don't see any disposing. I don't know MongoDB but is that safe?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, and you feel its justified, please consider marking it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Mongo (or the driver) handles some things for us, so I use the Create method:

```
MongoServer.Create(....)
```

instead of creating a new instance. The `Create` method will create a new instance or return an existing instance (it is unique per server settings).

In fact, just to show you the actual method I use currently:

```
internal static MongoDatabase DB(IMongoConfig config)
{
    return MongoServer
           .Create(config.ConnectionString)    //This bit is getting the MongoServer
           .GetDatabase(config.DatabaseName);  //This bit gets the Database, which is returned
}
```

`IMongoConfig` is just a little DTO I use to specify, as you can see, the connection string and DB name I need - this combined with the workings of `MongoServer.Create` make it quite easy to handle connections to multiple databases from the same running code base.

```
public interface IMongoConfig
    {
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Doesnt MongoServer.Create return a MongoServer object?

Comment: Yes it does, I mentioned it specifically because that (if I understand Mongo documentation correctly) is where the goodness happens. You would probably be more interested in my second code block where I use that to return the actual MongoDatabase - at the end of the day, our code is very similar to all intents and purposes, the main difference being how the MongoServer is inntantiated

Comment: Sorry but what I still dont understand is how your function can have a return type of MongoDatabase and return a MongoServer object (your second code block)

Comment: second code block returns a MongoDatabase, because of the .GetDatabase() method. Will reformat code, might make it clearer - let me know please.

Comment: Its all fine, Many Thanks.